# Contact Form 7 - New fields generate on button click

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want a button (other than the submit button), on click, to generate a set of new fields in a contact form.  I'm using Contact Form 7 on Wordpress.

```
$("table")
.on("click focus", ".item.inactive", function(e) {
    var curRow = $(".item.inactive"); 
    curRow.clone().appendTo("table tbody");
    curRow.removeClass("inactive").find("input:first").focus();
})
.on("click", ".icon.delete", function(e) {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});

$("button").on("click", function(e) {
$(".item.inactive").click().find("input:first").focus();
});
```

Like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Y8Vh9/23/

I have few questions that hopefully someone can answer.

Would I have to create a .js file? 
Or would I need to edit a js file in the plugin's folder?
Can I add the js snippet into the theme via Advanced Settings?
Or I would I need to modify additional files to have this work?

I'm a Wordpress newbie.

Thanks!

Comment: For the sake of simplicity and cleanliness, I would recommend creating a new, small, plugin to contain your modifications. Do not hack the contact-forms plugin, or your changes will be overwritten when you upgrade the plugin. Also, did you know about [wordpress.se](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I also recommend not including this in your theme. In general, it is a good practice to keep unnecessary dependencies to a minimum. By keeping this code out of your theme, you ensure that your theme is more likely to remain functional without contact-forms, or with a different implementation of the same features.

Comment: @Dan Ross No, I've never heard of wordpress.se, but I will definitely check that resource out.  Thank you for the tips.